# Deserialize Tekla Structures *.lis files

Tags: javascript, python, deserialization, bim

I need to deserialize `*.lis` files generated from a BIM software called Tekla Structures. The file looks like this:

```
PROFILE DATABASE EXPORT VERSION = 3

PROFILE_NAME = "HEA100";
{
    TYPE = 1; SUB_TYPE = 1001; COORDINATE = 0.000;
    {
        "HEIGHT"                            9.600000000E+001
        "WIDTH"                             1.000000000E+002
        "WEB_THICKNESS"                     5.000000000E+000
        "FLANGE_THICKNESS"                  8.000000000E+000
        ................................................
        .............more parameters here ..............
        ................................................
    }
}

PROFILE_NAME = "ANOTHER_PROFILE";
{
    TYPE = 1; SUB_TYPE = 1001; COORDINATE = 0.000;
    {
        "HEIGHT"                            9.600000000E+001
        "WIDTH"                             1.000000000E+002
        "WEB_THICKNESS"                     5.000000000E+000
        "FLANGE_THICKNESS"                  8.000000000E+000
        ................................................
        .............more parameters here ..............
        ................................................
    }
}
```

¿Is this related to a known serializing format?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a profile catalog. I did not find full documentation but Thekla support has a [commented example](https://teklastructures.support.tekla.com/de/2016i/en/mod_catalogs_example_export_file).

Comment: Yes I know. What I want to know if this file format is a well known format or it was specifically developed by Tekla. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is  a Tekla specific format. Never seen it somewhere else nor found any documentation on import or export in other software.